# Fill irregular area with grid

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, vertices, geometry

I want to fill a flat map of Europe with a grid. here is the map

[image: empty map]

I want it to look something like this but with the grid extended throughout. I tried to merge a plane into it and got this:

[image: partially filled map]

I was thinking a could maybe connect some vertices around the outside to make a square or hex shape and then grid fill on the simpler shape. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think this might be a case where a simple boolean is your best bet. Just make a grid that's bigger than the continent. Then extrude the continent through it so it has some volume and boolean the continent out of the grid.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying now. If I subdivide the plane too many times it messes up the boolean. I have to subdivide the plane only by 10 or a small number, and then do the boolean, and then I can subdivide the planes more